# rpc function error in Supabase with jsonb - Invalid input syntax for type json

Tags: postgresql, discord.js, jsonb, supabase, supabase-database

I have a Supabase table which stores data from a Discord guild. Data includes a list of current text channels within the guild the bot is in. The channels are currently stored as a JSONb under a guild_channels column, with each object within the JSONb array like this:

{id: channel_id, name: channel_name}

I can store channels fine. But when I try to use a bot listener for new channels added, I just cannot get the data to update. I am pulling the newly added channel no problem, but when I try to append a new channel object to the JSONb array within the supabase table, I just hit errors.

I am using an rpc function to handle this inside of Supabase as I couldn't find any other way to do it. But I cannot get it to work.

Here is the error I am currently seeing:

```
{
  code: '22P02',
  details: 'Expected ":", but found ",".',
  hint: null,
  message: 'invalid input syntax for type json'
}
```

And here is the function code inside of Supabase:

```
DECLARE
  channels JSONB;
BEGIN
  -- Retrieve the existing channels for the given guild_id
  SELECT guild_channels INTO channels FROM guilds WHERE guild_id = p_guild_id;

  -- Append the new channel to the channels array
  channels = COALESCE(channels, '[]'::JSONB) || jsonb_build_object("id", channel_id, "name", channel_name);

  -- Debugging: print the channels variable
  RAISE NOTICE 'Channels: %', channels;

  -- Update the guilds table with the new channels array
  UPDATE guilds SET guild_channels = channels WHERE guild_id = p_guild_id;
END;
```

Function is called here..

```
client.on("channelCreate", async (channel) => {
  if (channel.type === 0) {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.rpc("add_guild_channel", {
      p_guild_id: channel.guild.id,
      channel_id: channel.id,
      channel_name: channel.name,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }

    console.log(
      `Channel with ID ${channel.id} added to guild ${channel.guild.id}`
    );
  }
});
```

I have no idea what is going on, and I have been battling a myriad of errors with this all day. :(

Anyone help me with this?

Comment: You need to include the complete function. You have left parts out, like where `channel_id` and `channel_name` are coming from.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I have added this now. Thanks for replying. Any ideas on why this is not working?

Comment: No, I meant the complete function code  for `add_guild_channel()`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - Ah ok. It's created using the function feature inside of Supabase, so it's not entirely written out. The part I wrote out as code is in the description. The other parts that Supabase adds via inputs is the arguments, which are:

p_guild_id: TEXT
channel_id: TEXT
channel_name: TEXT

And what the function returns, which is set as: VOID

And language is: plpgsql

Does this help?

Comment: 1) No, Supabase does not add these they are defined when the function is created per [Supabase Create Function](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions). The function lives in the database. Using `psql` to connect to the database and run `\ef add_guild_channel`, you will get the complete function definition. 2) Can you modify the function?

Comment: In which line exactly is the error thrown (and do you get the raised notice)? Also can you post the schema of the `guilds` table as a SQL declaration?